# Get an audio element from a list using data-key in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm doing an exercise and I'm wondering how to do in `jQuery` to select an audio with a `data-key` attribute.

In JavaScript, this code works:

```
document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${evt.keyCode}"]`);
```

But in jQuery, I don't know how to get the audio element with the current event. I tried:

```
var audio = $('audio[data-key="'+$(this).keyCode+'"]');
```

But it's not this one either.

Can someone help me please? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var text = "abc";
  var divEle = $('div[data-key=' + text + ']');
  console.log($(divEle).text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div data-key="abc">ABC</div>
```

In your case the solution will be

```
 var keyCode = evt.keyCode;
 var audio = $('audio[data-key=' + keyCode + ']');
```